# ¿Cómo determino la palabra más larga y más corta de un string?, sin usar métodos o funciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Tengo este ejercicio:

Hacer un programa que solicite una cadena al usuario y determine en ella la palabra más larga y la palabra más corta que se ingresó, sin utilizar ninguno de los métodos de cadenas o similares que vienen con el Python. Unicamente se puede utilizar los operadores de comparación y de indexación y la función len() para realizar este programa. Por ejemplo en:

> " María tenía un corderito llamado Pepe "

la palabra más corta es "un" y la palabra más larga es "corderito".

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue usar el método .split(), pero en este caso me es inutil, ya que no lo puedo usar.

llevo esto hasta el momento pero no se como hacer que el ciclo continue con la otra palabra.

```
palabras = []
recolectador = ''
separador = ' '

cadena = "María tenía"
for i in range(len(cadena)):
    recolectador += cadena[i]

    if cadena[i] == separador:
        palabras.append(recolectador)
        recolectador = ''

print(palabras)
```

Comment: Richard  lo mas simple es iterar sobre la cadena (for in) y cada vez que te encuentres un espacio o espacios (comparador con if) compruebas la longitud de la palabra o la añades a una lista como hace split. Solo necesitas una variable que almacene el indice del primer carácter de cada palabra (carácter inicial de la cadena o siguiente a un espacio). Hay muchas formas de abordarlo en realidad.

Comment: Actualicé lo que llevo, aun no consigo que me de, no sé que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Richard he creado una respuesta comentando los problemas de tu código actual. Vas por buen camino en una de las posibles implementaciones, la idea es esa solo debes tener en cuenta algunos aspectos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vas por el buen camino en una de las posibles formas de abordar el problema creando tu propia versión de `str.split`, pero vamos a hacer unas cuantas observaciones sobre tu código:

```
for i in range(len(cadena)):
    recolectador += cadena[i]

    if cadena[i] == separador:
        palabras.append(recolectador)
        recolectador = ''
```

- Recorres la cadena y añades el carácter a `recolectador` sea cual sea. Esto es un error, porque también añades el separador. Debes hacer primero la comparación con `if` y luego si no es un separador añadir el carácter.
- El siguiente problema es que si el carácter es el separador, añades el contenido de `recolectador` a la lista, aunque esta cadena esté vacía. Puedes obtener un `recolectador` vacío si la cadena empieza por un espacio o si tiene varios espacios concatenados. Debes añadir `recolectador` a la lista solo si no es una cadena vacía, basta con un condicional dentro de tu `if` para comprobar esto.
- Esto es solo una recomendación, deberías usar `for in` para recorrer el array y no `for` + `range` +`len` + indexación. Es mucho más eficiente, más legible y más sencillo.

Tu código podría ser algo así:

```
palabras = []
recolectador = ''
separador = ' '

cadena = " María tenía un corderito llamado Pepe "
for caracter in cadena:
    if caracter == separador:
        if recolectador: # Solo si la cadena no está vacía la añadimos
            palabras.append(recolectador)
            recolectador = ''
    else:
        recolectador += caracter

print(palabras)
```

Ahora solo te queda recorrer la lista con otro `for in` y con ayuda de `len` buscar la palabra mayor y  menor.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solución pero se podría simplificar más:

```
p=" María tenía un corderito llamado Pepe "
z,n=0,0
mayor=''
menor=p
while z<len(p):
    for letra in p[z:len(p)] :
        z+=1
        n+=1
        if letra==' ':
            break
    if p[z-n:z-1]!='':
        if len(p[z-n:z-1])>=len(mayor):
            mayor=p[z-n:z-1]
        if len(p[z-n:z-1])<=len(menor):
            menor=p[z-n:z-1]
    n=0
print mayor
print menor
```

Ahora bien con lista se podria hacer cambiando tu condicional en el loop y agregando un for para comparar y encontrar la palabra mas larga y la mas corta

```
palabras = []
recolectador = ''
separador = ' '

cadena = "María tenía un corderito"
for i in range(len(cadena)):
    recolectador += cadena[i]
    if (cadena[i] == separador or i==len(cadena)-1)and recolectador!=' ':
        palabras.append(recolectador)
        recolectador = ''

mayor=palabras[0]
menor=palabras[0]

for i in palabras:
    if len(i)>=len(mayor):
        mayor=i
    if len(i)<=len(menor):
        menor=i

print mayor
print menor
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una variante algo sencilla pero creo que cumple con el enunciado

```
oracion = " María tenía un corderito llamado Pepe "
mayor=""
menor=""
palabra=""

for c in oracion:
  if c == " ":
    if palabra != "":
      mayor = palabra if len(mayor)<len(palabra) or mayor == "" else mayor
      menor = palabra if len(menor)>len(palabra) or menor == "" else menor

    palabra = ""

  palabra = palabra + c

print(mayor)
print(menor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hallé una forma de hacer esto sin tanto código en python:

```
txt = input()
words=txt.split(" ")
nList=[]

for i in words:
 nList.append(len(i))

dir=nList.index(max(nList))

print(words[dir])
```

y ya xd, funcional y corto

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un servicio de código (no es dejar el código y ya), sino también se debe explicar lo que hace. Puede que otras personas vean más adelante esta respuesta y no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).